# Remove Base reference from derived class debug view

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 2 classes, one inherit from anotherone

```
public class A
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I create a List of class B and cast it into a type of class B

```
List<B> BList = new List<B>();
BList = new List<B>() { new B() { prop1 = "1", prop2 = "2", prop3 = "3", prop4 = "4" } };
List<A> AList = BList.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

But when I debug, there is still a reference to class B:
[image]

How can I remove / avoid the display of properties from the base class?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this?  Is it just to make debugging easier / less cluttered?  If not, then do you really need one class to inherit from the other?

Comment: If `B` inherits from `A`, there will always be a reference from `B` to `A`. How would you want to avoid it and most importantly, why?

Comment: This makes no sense at all as there is *no* reference to `A`, as `B`already *is* an `A`-instance. What you see in the debugger is just the instance of `B` casted to `A`.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)? That doesn't happen in .NET.

Comment: @c0rd Is that because you want to prevent end users from accessing the properties in the base class? What reason do you want to do this?

Comment: the reason is, that i pass `A` within a WCF Service and i always get the exception `Error while Deserializing B` - invalid contract type. So he recognizes somehow the wrong type

Comment: Even if that would exist in .NET, the slice works in the opposite direction, thus when you cast a derived instance to its base-class you´re losing the information from the *derived* one. What you want is to omit the information from the *base*-class which is pure non-sense.

Comment: @c0rd if your contract requires a B then passing A does not fulfill the contract. You could relax the contract to allow A and then add B as a KnownType via the KnownTypeAttribute.

Comment: thank you so far i'll ask this in another question, thats something else

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, HimBromBeere, walther   I put this into another question since the reason was not good enough explained http://stackoverflow.com/q/39613957/6755471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove this but you can make it appear differently in the debugger.
Use a debugger type proxy as [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx) to display the class in the debugger the way you prefer. Lists and dictionaries are done this way so you could check out the source code for that using a decompiler such as ILSpy.

For example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(BDebugView))]
public class B : A
{
    private class BDebugView
    {
        private B _actualObject;
        public string prop4 { get { return _actualObject.prop4; } }

        public BDebugView(B actualObject)
        {
            this._actualObject = actualObject;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that should do it, I haven't tested though.

Comment: Maybe you could show an example of this and how it looks in the debugger? Sounds interesting to me.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've added an example for the curious. I can't recommend enough also to get ILSpy (or Reflector) and start checking out the inner workings of the base class library.

Comment: Cool, didn´t know this feature. However it won´t help OP as he´s trying something totally different as seen in his comment.